# When is this integral zero?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, anharmonic-oscillators

I have a particle with total energy $E$ confined in a potential
$$U(x) = -\frac{\cos^4x}{2} - m \cos x - f \sin x. $$
The constants $f$ and $m$ are both in the range (-2,2). The energy is such that the particle is in a bound state, with turning points $x_1$ and $x_2$ on either side of the origin.

I want to make the following statement:

> If and only if $f = 0$,
>   $$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{\sin x dx}{\sqrt{E - U(x)}} = 0.$$

One direction of the implication is simple. If $f=0$, the potential is even, and $x_1 = -x_2$. Since the integrand is odd, this integral obviously vanishes. But I'm struggling with showing that the integral is zero only if $f = 0$. Is this true? My numerical solutions to the equations of motion seem to indicate so.

EDIT: I evaluated the integral numerically in Mathematica with $E = -2,~m = 2$, and for a wide range of values of $f$. The plot below shows the value of the integral on the vertical axis, and the input $f$ value on the horizontal. It looks like any proof relying on monotonicity will not work.

[image: m = 2, E = -2]

Comment: Examine the integrand to see when it is an even or odd function.

Comment: If $f \ne 0$, it is neither. I don't see how that would be relevant anyway, since the region we integrate over is not symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating the whole integral with respect to $f$ shows that it is strictly  monotone decreasing in $f$ for $x_1<x_2$. Therefore $f=0$ is the only solution.

$$\frac{d}{df}\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{\sin x dx}{\sqrt{E - U(x)}}=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{\sin^2 x dx}{\sqrt{E - U(x)}^3}<0$$

Comment: This is a suggestion I heard from a friend, but I'm a little wary of this derivative. Do we need to take into account the fact that the turning points change with $f$?

Comment: yes, you're right. The turning points change...